# Add second sign up screen to social sign up allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using the django allauth auth system and I use the social sign ups with the "next" parameter like this:

```
<a data-provider="facebook"
   href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" next=next %}">
```

where next is a dynamic variable.

However i would like to inject a second screen to the process, asking for i.e. a phoner number or other info.

I imagine I would need to override a method to redirect to the second screen and pass the next parameter to this view.

Any idea which method to override?

Edit:
I figured out how to do this for the "normal" sign up flow:

I overrode the allauth.account.views.SignupView and added a new method:

```
class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        next_value = (get_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                            self.redirect_field_name)
                      or self.success_url)
        ret = 'whatever/url?next=' + next_value
        return ret

signup = CustomSignupView.as_view()
```

And then added the custom view to my own accounts/signup url file.

**But** I cant find that method in the **social** sign up view. Does anybody have an idea where the next parameter gets evaluated in the social sign up view?

Edit2:

So I did some digging. The Flag is used in the sociallogin classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def state_from_request(cls, request):
    if next_url:
        state['next'] = next_url
    return state
```

After that its passed over the provider to helpers complete_social_login or complete_social_signup (not sure yet when what is called).

In the end there is a function account/utils perform_login that actually executes the redirect.

Not sure where to override as of now, still digging.

So finally it comes to:

The socialaccount view calls helpers.complete_social_signup which then calls complete signup with the redirect url.

I think ill have to override that view and then pass my own complete social signup method.

Edit3:

If you have autosignup enabled (which I do) the SocialSignup ClassView will never be invoked, instead the new user is created in socialaccount.helpers._process_signup.

Comment: You want to ask for extra info before they authorized using social? Or after?

Comment: After, so I can confirm their social data and ask extra info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up **[forking](https://github.com/JulianSchneider/django-allauth)** django-allauth and simply adding a setting for a callable called ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT.

```
def custom_signup_redirect(success_url):
    ret = '/whatever/url/?next=' + success_url
    return ret
```

and then in settings:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT = 'myapp.utils.custom_signup_redirect'
```

See [this](https://github.com/JulianSchneider/django-allauth/commit/ff87a6727d0873fe7db9fda1c4273ddf69a22952) commit.